# cmake find_package not working on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cmake, gsl

Just attempting to create my first cmake project. I have a very simple setup but cannot seem to get find_package to work. I am on Mac OS X 10.9.3 and installed cmake from the dmg package (cmake version 2.8.12.2). I have created a very simple CMakeLists.txt as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (Tutorial)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} “${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules”)
message( STATUS ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} )
FIND_PACKAGE(GSL REQUIRED)

add_executable(Tutorial src/main.cpp)
```

and have placed the FindGSL.cmake file (downloaded) in the cmake/Module folder as shown by my terminal output:

```
bash-3.2$ ls cmake/Modules/
FindGSL.cmake
```

I then get the following output from cmake:

```
bash-3.2$ cmake ../
-- “/Users/adam/repos/ctmc/cmake/Modules”
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "FindGSL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "GSL", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "GSL" with any of
  the following names:

    GSLConfig.cmake
    gsl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "GSL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "GSL_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "GSL" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/adam/repos/ctmc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure that file `/Users/adam/repos/ctmc/cmake/Modules/FindGSL.cmake` exists?

Comment: Weird, yes checked in finder and from command line just seems not to find it, was wondering if it was permissions on file or some environment variable I need set! I will try on another computer when I get back

Comment: I tried it on a Linux box as well and get the same error. Will it give this message if there is an error in the FindGSL.cmake file

Comment: Just to note I have got it all working by using INCLUDE instead of FIND_PACKAGE. Not sure why find_package is not working for me

Comment: `using INCLUDE instead of FIND_PACKAGE` it's not the same and yes, this is really weird)

Comment: `if it was permissions on file` and what permissions has file `FindGSL.cmake` when `include` command works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `cmake/Modules` directory permissions. You don't have `execute` permissions for
directory so **you can read** file if you have **full path** to it, but you can't find it:

```
> ls cmake/Modules/FindMy.cmake 
cmake/Modules/FindMy.cmake
> cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Foo)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules")
find_package(My REQUIRED)
> cmake -H. -B_builds
... OK
```

And again without `x`-permission

```
> chmod -x cmake/Modules/
> rm -rf _builds/
> cmake -H. -B_builds
...
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindMy.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked
  CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "My", but CMake did
  not find one.
```

Comment: Great!! That worked cheers for the help I knew it had to be something silly I was doing