How to add "Framework Search Path" via CMake?
I'm trying to add several Qt frameworks to the project via cmake

  target_link_libraries(Maya::${mayaVersion}::Qt INTERFACE "--framework ${mayaLibraryDir}/QtCore" 
                                                           "--framework ${mayaLibraryDir}/QtGui"
                                                           "--framework ${mayaLibraryDir}/QtWidgets"
                                                           "--framework ${mayaLibraryDir}/QtOpenGL" "")


While project is generated succesfully it fails to compile because of missing headers, e.g.

fatal error: 'QString' file not found

Header files are located in *.framework files
However, trying to add includes from *.framework does not solve the issue.

  target_include_directories(Maya::${mayaVersion}::Qt INTERFACE 
                                                           "${mayaLibraryDir}/QtCore.framework/Headers" 
                                                           "${mayaLibraryDir}/QtGui.framework/Headers"
                                                           "${mayaLibraryDir}/QtWidgets.framework/Headers"
                                                           "${mayaLibraryDir}/QtOpenGL.framework/Headers" "")


With the above I'm getting errors about missing headers from the Qt files themselves:

/osx64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qplaintextedit.h:7:10: fatal
error: 'QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h' file not found [build] #include
<QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h>
So this seems to be not the intended way of adding headers from frameworks.

In the project settings I found the following:

Which makes me think that the supposed way is to somehow add these "Framework Search Paths".
But how that can be done via CMake?
Thus far I have not found any information on the subject...

I mostly use Linux but what you look for likely relates to: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097327/cmake-find-package-not-working-on-mac-os-x
